# How to gracefully override the old css with a new css by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div element, with css-->class 1, like the following codes:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .class1 {width: 100px !important;padding-top:10px;margin-bottom: 22px;}
</style>

<div class="class1"></div>
```

My target is to change this div element's width to 300px.
My original solution is pretty straight-forward by using jQuery:

```
 $('div').find(".class1").each(function () {
      this.style.setProperty(  "width", "300px", "important" );
 });
```

However, our technical lead thought this is so hacky, and asked me to do it as part of a style sheet instead.

He suggested that maybe I can attach a marker class to that div element, to trigger the different behavior.

So, my plan is to add new css class--> class2, and then try to add/apply this new class to div element, like the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
      .class2 {width: 300px !important;}
</style>

$('div').find(".class1").each(function () {
      $(this).addClass("class2");
 });
```

However, class1 still has higher priority than class2, so the width is still 100px.

That means I need to remove class1 before class 2 applies, like

```
 $('div').find(".class1").each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("class1").addClass("class2");
 });
```

But, if class1 has many settings/properties, that means I need to copy them into class2 for keeping the result still the same, except the width.

Is there any elegant way to "only" override the width setting of class1 if class2 only contains the new width setting?

Comment: remove the !important in both class and put class2 under class1 in the file define them and it should work.

Comment: @thinh.lam, is there any way that we don't edit the class1 definition since we still need it for other scenarios/functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define the CSS rule as follows:

```
.class1.class2 { width: 300px !important};
```

and you could add it either to an embedded style sheet or to an external
style sheet.

You can then use JavaScript to add the new selector `.class2` to the element of interest.

The CSS rule with `.class1.class2` will have higher selectivity than `.class1` and override the width setting.

Using this approach, you don't have to remove `class1` from the `class` attribute and you don't have to worry too much about whether the rule for `.class1` is defined before or after `.class1.class2`.